# How do I center a jPanel on a page that is printed?

Tags: java, printing

I am getting my receipt to print, which is great. Is there a straight-forward way of centering the jPanel on the page when it is printed?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a semi-straightforward way.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
  Component myPanel =...;
  g.translate(pf.getImageableX() + pf.getImageableWidth() / 2 - myPanel.getWidth() / 2, pf.getImageableY() + pf.getImageableHeight() / 2 - myPanel.getHeight() / 2);
  //Graphics object has been set up so the printing myPanel with it should now be centered
  myPanel.print(g);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed! I guess it just took some math and understanding of the page format and using the width of the panel to my advantage. Thank you for your help.